# How to beautify shell string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting strings from a shell output. They are formated using the shell colors *eg* :

```
[2m36:13 [22m [31mabcdefgh...xyz [39m
```

[image: list of color definitions]

I'd like to show the formated string in a browser, *i.e.* with colors and without their definitions.

So is there any library or React Component for that ?

Thanks

edit : I'd like something like this :

```
function shell2Html(str) { /* ... */ }
shell2Html("[2m36:13 [22m [31mabcdefgh...xyz [39m")
// returns "<span class="red"><span class="bold">abcdefgh</span></span>"
```

Comment: Show formatted string in a browser? do you mean browser console?

Comment: No !! I want to transform a _shell string_ `[2m36:13 [22m [31mabcdefgh...xyz [39m` to an _html string_ `<span class="red bold">abcd</span>`

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, you can use span with styles to achieve that. As you are already getting strings, you can use it and generate html and render on browser

Comment: So, due to complexity, I was wondering if anyone knew a library !?

Comment: Not sure what is the shell and what exactly you are trying to achieve
More info would be helpful

Comment: shell : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell

Answer (score 1):

You can add CSS in console.log messages:

```
console.log('%cHello World', 'color: red');
```

Comment: Okay, then add more information to your question, otherwise, nobody can help you